# Datagridview clicked header first cell exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I have a big problem. I ran into it while developing a windows-form application. I placed a datagridview with 4 columns and a few rows on the form. When I click on the header of the first column it throws an error message. I also attached this. I tried to specify a condition for the "CellClick" event so as not to cause a problem. Unfortunately, he didn't solve it. Strange because this error phenomenon is not present in the additional columns. Whatever I tried and modified I couldn’t eliminate. Sor[image: ry for my English.]
CellClick event handler code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)
            return;
    }
```

Comment: please post the exception details in english lol

Comment: Sorry. "Object type can only be DateTime."

Comment: welp that almost seems like there is something else going on... Your code looks okay. Maybe place a breakpoint in the click handler and stept through the code? is this the only code in DellContentClick? I believe there is also a CellDoubleContentClick or something - do you use that?

Comment: I tried this method, the variable value was -1. Unfortunately, the CellDoubleContentClick event was not success too. And DellContentClick event I not find.

Comment: well - without more information there's nothing we can do really...

Comment: Sorry, I have no information this problem. When program is run and I click the datagridview not call this function.

Comment: Do not use CellContentClick unless you can actually click the __content__. Use the other events!

Comment: Which event, that I should use for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that first column is used to display DateTime values and that the [DataGridViewColumn.SortMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.sortmode?view=netframework-4.8) is set to `DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic`.  When you click on the column header, the DGV tries to sort the column.

The problem is that in one or more rows the value stored in cell[0] is not either a DateTime value or null.  This is why you are receiving the error message of:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Object must be of type DateTime.'

If you do not want the column to automatically sort, set the SortMode property to either `DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable` or `DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic`.